# How to make TextView appear when app is run?

Tags: java, android, textview

My text views aren't appearing when running the app. I've tried adjusting the visibility and elevation. I've looked online and none of the answers worked.
How do I fix this? (Java)

[This is the render in android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VfqHO.png)

[This is the emulator, my physical phone shows the same thing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRyNt.png)

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/cardview_light_background"
    android:elevation="-1dp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.GrubhubWheel.FullscreenContainer">

    <!-- The primary full-screen view. This can be replaced with whatever view
         is needed to present your content, e.g. VideoView, SurfaceView,
         TextureView, etc. -->

    <!-- This FrameLayout insets its children based on system windows using
         android:fitsSystemWindows. -->
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/gear"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_settings_5672"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Blind"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/yaro_st"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display3"
            android:textColor="#010101"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="Blind" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Ate"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/galano_grotesque_alt_semi_bold"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Display4"
            android:textColor="#4ca66c"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/Blind"
            tools:text="Ate" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/wheel"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_marginVertical="10dp"
            android:backgroundTint="@android:color/transparent"
            android:elevation="-1dp"
            android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="true"
            android:rotation="15"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/Ate"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.85"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/random_wheel"
            tools:ignore="SpeakableTextPresentCheck,ImageContrastCheck" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: Use `android:text="Ate"` instead of `tools:text="Ate"`

Comment: Any argument in the xml with `tools:` is just used when showing it in Android Studio and will have no effect on an actual device or emulator.